# Ubuntu kicks Windows users from WiFi

Tags: wireless, networking, windows

I've some serious problems, when I start my Ubuntu laptop and connect to WiFi some (not all) other Windows-laptops loses connection from our network. Then, when they try to reconnect they'll receive a "Windows could not connect to network.." error. After the router is being restarted, and I don't connect with my Ubuntu laptop, it just works fine. When I connect, its about 1 minute before they'll lose there connection..

I've a TL-WR1043ND (TP-Link) router and my Ubuntu notebook is an Acer Aspire V3-772G. Resetting router to factory settings won't work, using an WPA2-PSK security. No IP conflict.. (Everything is through DHCP and I don't have a static ip)

I don't know where to ask first, but I'll think it should be something with my Ubuntu installation, that's the reason I'll ask here first :)

Thanks

The `lspci -nn | grep 0280` command will return:

```
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
```

Some more debug information from the Windows notebooks:

```
Details about wireless connectivity diagnosis:

For complete information about this session see the wireless connectivity information event.

Helper Class: Auto Configuration
Initialize status: Success

Information for connection being diagnosed
Interface GUID: (REMOVED)
Interface name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6230
Interface type: Native WiFi
Profile: HomeWireless
SSID: HomeWireless
SSID length: 12
Connection mode: Infra
Security: Yes
Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No

Result of diagnosis: Problem found
Issue referred to: RNWF MSM Helper Class

Root cause:
Windows could not connect to "HomeWireless"
You can try to connect again.

Repair option:
Reset your wireless network adapter
This will disable and then enable the network adapter "Wireless Network Connection" on this computer.
Informational
Diagnostics Information (Wireless Network Adapter)
Details about wireless network adapter diagnosis:

For complete information about this session see the wireless connectivity information event.

Helper Class: Native WiFi MSM
Initialize status: Success

Information for connection being diagnosed
Interface GUID: (REMOVED)
Interface name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6230
Interface type: Native WiFi
Profile: HomeWireless
SSID: HomeWireless
SSID length: 12
Connection mode: Infra
Security: Yes
Connect even if network is not broadcasting: No

Result of diagnosis: Problem found

Root cause:
Wireless association to "HomeWireless" failed
A response was not received from the router or access point.

Detailed root cause:
Wireless association to this network failed. Windows did not receive any response from the wireless router or accesspoint.

Repair option:
Look for causes of low wireless signal quality
The signal is weak due to distance or interference.
Windows Help and Support can provide more information about this problem.
```

And when the Windows machine got disconnected (this screenshot is another DHCP request, because the log was cleared) every time he "retries" I'll see this in my Router log:
http://screenshot.wouter0100.nl/1396474377232014021396474377.png
Only these 2 entries, which normally are much more..

Comment: are you running a dhcp or dns server on your ubuntu machine?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. I'll take a look. dnsmasq was running, could it be that one?

Comment: My guess is that you have a Broadcom wireless device with a non-optimum driver! Please edit your question to add details of your device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Information added

Comment: Sounds like a Windows problem.  If you boot the Ubuntu live cd in one of these other computers and run that for a bit, does it still get kicked off while running Ubuntu?

Comment: What are the IPs on the windows machines when they can't connect? and when they can?

Comment: IP adresses are always between 100 and 199 (default DHCP configuration @router). When they can't connect, idk what they have for an IP :P It isn't a conflict. (Not the same as mine)

Comment: Possibly they have no IP or an invalid one like 169. This is just to check if your problem is network or dns. When they can't connect, can they ping by IP on LAN or on internet?

Comment: They just receive an error like (http://helpdeskgeek.com/wp-content/pictures/2011/12/windows-cannot-connect.jpg?d620e9). They don't even get connected..

Comment: Could the issue be too many connected devices for the router to handle?

Comment: Don't think so, never had this problem and it's ONLY with my Ubuntu desktop. Mac notebooks aren't effected....

Comment: Added much more information, now tried enabling AP Isolation, this isn't a good solution, but on this way I'm sure it's my notebook.. Seems to be working :S

Comment: Find out it hasn't anything todo with Ubuntu, AP isolation didn't work for sure, now, when another Windows notebook connects, it will disconnect the same notebook as yesterday :P.. Damn...

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone the MAC address of one of your network cards from the other laptops, and use it in Ubuntu for eth0 / dhcp cable connection. See if you get the same problems with the other laptops which are running Windows once you cloned the mac address from a computer running Windows to the one running Ubuntu.

My guess is that your ISP does not allow you to use your Internet connection for more than 1-2 computers, and this is why you get these errors. Maybe they want you to pay something extra to be able to use more computers with the same connection...?

Comment: I've an own router, which currently 2 tablets, 4 smartphones and 2 computers (excluding myself) connected. At the peak about 9 smartphones, 4 tables and ~5 computers. This won't be a problem, I think :(

Comment: It should be a problem if you have a DSL/Cable connection of max. 100 mb/s.

Comment: We've here fiberglass. Never had this before..

Comment: If your router is doing NAT (and I suppose it does), the MAC address stay local and the ISP only provides 1 IP fo any number of computers connected. Anyways, from the error mesage, the problem is not only with internet but with LAN network too.